# Problems initializing glut

Tags: c++, glut

I have simplified my problem to this example:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition( 0, 0 );

    int win = glutCreateWindow("Recon");

    return 0;
}
```

When it executes the glutCreateWindow, it takes about 1 minute and the screens flicker several times.

This is ridiculously long. This can't be normal.

Environment:

- Fedora 10
- Dual NVIDIA GTX280 cards driving 3 monitors.
- NVIDIA driver version 190.53 CUDA 2.3 installed
- gcc version 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7) (GCC)

Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Edit: I have no display function because my ultimate goal is to create a rendering context so that I can create a Pixel Buffer Object from some CUDA code (which for the moment is not going to be displaying its output. I have also tried creating a context with a series of glx calls with the same delay and flickering happening when gkxMakeCurrent is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a display function?
I'm not sure if this will help, but maybe putting in a display function in which you clear the buffers might help?

e.g.
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);

```
void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the screen
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

What compiler are you using? And, have you looked into any possible performance issues associated with Fedora 10 and openGL (I'm looking into the second bit right now).

Edit: There are definitely some anecedotal stories of a performance hit in Fedora 10
[Here](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=131190) and [Here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=473179). The second one seems to describe at least one of your symptoms. Are you able to try your code on another OS?

Comment: Thanks. See my edits for some answers. I need to run this eventually on Debian 5, so I may try that now. Well, tomorrow. :)

Comment: Accepted - problem not seen in Debian 5.